# improvement in slicing data?

Tags: python-3.x, slice

**BACKGROUND**

I have a piece of hardware that returns an ascii stream & the user can choose

1. the number of timesteps
2. the number of channels

One packet = [ADDRESS][MSB][LSB][CHECKSUM]

One timestamp = [TIME_PACKET][CH1_PACKET][CH2_PACKET][CH3_PACKET][CH4_PACKET][CH5_PACKET][CH6_PACKET][CH7_PACKET]

Below is some stripped down code that I use to create 7 plus time arrays to then plot via matplotlib. The issue is, it takes a fair amount of time to process... 2.7seconds for 30,000 samples & 7 channels. I have used cython and I compiled this block down as a C extension and it isn't that much faster...

COMPLETE time is 2.7seconds.
Disable Checksum is 1.8seconds  # this one test is 0.9seconds
Disable sign extend is 1.8seconds # this one test is 0.9 seconds
Disable all checks is 1.0 seconds

so roughly half the time is splitting the data
1/4 of the time is Checksum check on each packet
1/4 of the time is sign extend check on each packet

those checks are quite important as they help identify framing errors w.r.t. the USB link & also any noise pickup on the piece of test equipment (so the top 4bits then start being incorrectly set...)

Is the below code reasonably efficient and should I live with it or is it really really bad...

```
import numpy as np
import time

BIT_LENGTH=16 # payload bitlength
num_samples=30000 # number of samples
packet = 4 # 4 bytes

chT = b'\x01\x00\x05\xfb' # timestep of 5 @ 1
ch1 = b'\x03\x00\x11\xed' # data 17 @ 3
ch2 = b'\x04\x00\x07\xfc' # data 7 @ 4
ch3 = b'\x08\x00\x17\xe0' # data 23 @ 8
ch4 = b'\x0c\x00e\x96'    # data 101 @ 12
ch5 = b'\x0e\x00\x01\xf0' # data 1 @ 14
ch6 = b'\x13\x04\x00\xe8' # data 1024 @ 19
ch7 = b'\x14\x04\xd2='    # data 1234 @ 20

stream = chT+ch1+ch2+ch3+ch4+ch5+ch6+ch7
stream = stream*num_samples
req = [1,3,4,8,12,14,19,20]  # array of channel addresses.
req_array = [np.zeros(num_samples) for i in req] # init np arrays.


fpga_error_codes = {
        '\x80\x00\x01':'ERR 1', 
        '\x80\x00\x02':'ERR 2', 
        '\x80\x00\x04':'ERR 3', 
        '\x80\x00\x08':'ERR 4', 
        '\x80\x00\x10':'ERR 5', 
        '\x80\x00\x20':'ERR 6', 
        '\x80\x00\x40':'ERR 7',
}

class PacketError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.parameter = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.parameter)

### FUNCTIONS USED
def checksum(data):
    return (~(data[0] ^ data[1] ^ data[2]) & 0xff).to_bytes(1,byteorder='big',signed=False)


def check_packet_bits(data, s=None, nbits=BIT_LENGTH):
    ''' additional method to assist with error detection'''
    int_data = int.from_bytes(data[1:-1],byteorder='big',signed=True)
    if s=='unsigned':
        if int_data > (2**nbits)-1:
            return True # ERROR!
        else:
            return False
    elif s == 'signed':
        hi = 2**(nbits -1) -1
        lo = -1 * 2**(nbits-1)
        return True if int_data < lo else True if int_data > hi else False
def check_packet(addr, data, num_bits=BIT_LENGTH, sign_type='signed'):
    '''Method to determine whether an ITI packet is valid'''
    if checksum(data[:-1]) != data[-1].to_bytes(1,byteorder='big',signed=False):
        msg = 'Checksum Error: %s' % ( ' '.join([hex(i) for i in data]) )
        raise PacketError(msg)
    elif data[0] == '\x80':
        msg = "%sd      %s" %(fpga_error_codes.get(data[:3],'Unspecified Error'),' '.join([hex(i) for i in data]) )
        raise PacketError(msg)
    elif data[0] != addr:
        msg = "Wrong addr. Got: %d Want: %d      %s" % (data[0],addr,' '.join([hex(i) for i in data]) )
        raise PacketError(msg)
    elif check_packet_bits(data,s=sign_type, nbits=num_bits):
        msg = "Target FPGA sent a corrupted payload addr: %d, page: %d Data: 0x%02x%02x" %(addr, self.present_page,data[1],data[2])
        raise PacketError(msg)
    else:
        return int.from_bytes(data[1:-1],byteorder='big',signed=True)






t0= time.time()
### CODE IN QUESTION 
timestep_iter = zip(*(iter(stream),)*packet*len(req))
for entry,time_window in enumerate(timestep_iter):
    packet_iter = zip(*(iter(bytes(time_window)),)*packet)
    tmp = [check_packet(i,bytes(next(packet_iter)),sign_type=['signed','unsigned'][0],num_bits=12,) for i in req]
    for index,addr in enumerate(req):
        req_array[index][entry] = tmp[index]

req_array[0] = req_array[0].cumsum() - req_array[0]
### CODE IN  QUESTION
print(time.time()-t0)
```

Comment: At a guess, I'd say it's what you'd get by using Python. So the timing may be reasonable. Two things: 1/ there are several flags and tweaks in Cython to disable some checks, have you tried setting those? 2/ You use numpy exactly once (to initialize `req_array`), but then index each element separately in a loop. Perhaps there are some places you can actually more numpy-esque code (from a first glance, it doesn't look that, but perhaps some restructuring can help).

Comment: thanks, I just wanted to be sure I had not made some massive mistake and was eating cycle for no reason... The reason I am re-looking at this is because I am going to attempt streaming. Pulling 10,000 samples (100us step) is a new block every 1second. If I can do the initial processing before the next packet is due It should be ok.

Comment: You can change the zips to izips from itertools.  That way you're not building lists instead you're working purely with iterators.  That is the only thing that really sticks out to me.